# How can I ignore any changes in a particular folder from Git

Tags: github

I want to exclude the changes in all  files in a folder Api\Bin*.* and Core\obj*.* into GitHub merging. I dont want to consider that folder while merging the changes. How can I do that Please advise. I have added the following line of code in ignored file from Repository->Setting->Ignored files , but not working . When compile the program , still obj and bin folder files is showed in changes of GitHub
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line in gitingore files following ways

```
logs/
```

These lines will ignore the logs folder. Even you can use patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If those files are already tracked, no amount of `.gitignore` would work.

You need to remove them first (from the Git index, not from your disk)

```
git rm --cached -r API/bin/
git rm --cached -r Core/obj/
```

Then check (no commit needed) if you see them in GitHub Desktop.

You can also see if your .gitignore rules apply with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- Core/obj/<anObjFile>
```